# {"error":{"code":"InvalidContentLink","message":"Unable to download deployment content

Tags: azure

Below is the code used for deployment in Azure:

```
templateLink: {
    uri: "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4443/fulfillment_engine/resources/azure/tmp_miaasafd7c68e51f3_1/template.json",
}
```

Error:

> {"error":{"code":"InvalidContentLink","message":"Unable to download
>   deployment content from
>   'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4443/fulfillment_engine/resources/azure/tmp_miaasafd7c68e51f3_1/template.json'.
>   The tracking Id is 'a361db85-8982-4afc-b0c4-94f9f8ba2bef'. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details."}}

The same code is used but on a different port 4080 and it works properly.

When port from 4080 to 4443 is changed, it gives error.

Comment: The link should be public, could you access the link from your local?

Comment: the link should be accessible publicly and without any authorization, unless you are using azure storage and sas tokens

Comment: Yes, the link is accessible from my local web browser. When opened in IE, it will ask to accept the certificate.

Comment: Hi Anh, wonder if you have solved the problem, I am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Changing the access level of the resource worked for me (I used the container).

Comment: I'm not sure why you think OP is using blob storage